# SwiperJS smooth auto height fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

Can anyone help by suggesting how to make the open/close toggle smoother?

I've used the swiper.updateAutoHeight(speed) property from the the [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events) to readjust the wrapper height when the expandable div opens and closes...

```
    $('.options').click(function() {
      $(this).children('.content').toggleClass("open"),
    setTimeout(function() {swiper.updateAutoHeight(200)}, 400);
    });
```

Please see the fiddle below an click the open/close text to see the transition I'm trying to smooth out

http://jsfiddle.net/guildof1/j3wb7L4v/

Many thanks in advance!